# segmentation fault: 11, when using Alamofire.upload

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xcode8

I updated Alamofire to 4.0 for swift 3. (before i was using AFNetworking).

My Code:

```
func uploadImage(_ image: Data, withURLRequrest urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, responseCallback: ((NetworkResponse) -> ())? = nil) {


    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        _ = multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: image, name: "imagefile", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

        }, with: urlRequest) { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let json):

                        if let responseCallback = responseCallback {
                            responseCallback(.success(Response(response: json)))
                        }

                    case .failure(_): break

                    }

                }
            case .failure(let encodingError): break
            }

    }

}
```

I get a compile error:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11.

and is the details i get a lot of garbage paths and a stack trace (not from my code)

and in the end:

> 1. While emitting SIL for 'uploadImage' at */Network/APIManager.swift:64:5

This in pointing to the function above.

Any suggestions? 
Any other REST request is working (not multipart).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API of `multipartFormData` has changed.

The `append` method now look like this (Note that it doesn't return any value):

`func append(_ data: Data, withName name: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)`

Here is the example from the Alamofire's README:

```
Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(unicornImageURL, withName: "unicorn")
        multipartFormData.append(rainbowImageURL, withName: "rainbow")
    },
    to: "https://httpbin.org/post",
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update CocoaPods. Not

```
pod update
```

I mean update the entire CocoaPods to 1.0.0

Comment: I did - didnt work

$ sudo gem update cocoapods
Password:
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
$ pod --version
1.0.1